# yocto systemd can service not start after boot

Tags: yocto, systemd

I try to add can0 to systemd to auto start at boot time on my imx8 board. 
But I couldnt with these configurations :

```
$tree recipes-core/
----------------------------------------
recipes-core/
└── systemd
    ├── systemd-machine-units
    │   ├── 10-eth0.network
    │   ├── 10-eth1.network
    │   ├── 90-dhcp-default.network
    │   ├── can0.service
    │   └── can1.service
    └── systemd-machine-units_1.0.bbappend

2 directories, 6 files
```

```
$ cat systemd-machine-units_1.0.bbappend 
-------------------------------------------------------------
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

# all our boards have at least one native network port
SRC_URI = " \
    file://10-eth0.network \
    file://90-dhcp-default.network \
    file://10-eth1.network \
    file://can0.service \
    file://can1.service \
"

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "can0.service can1.service"


do_install_append() {
    install -d ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/network/
    install -m 0644 "${WORKDIR}/10-eth0.network" ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/network/
    install -m 0644 "${WORKDIR}/90-dhcp-default.network" ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/network/
    install -m 0644 "${WORKDIR}/10-eth1.network" ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/network/
    install -d ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}/
    install -m 0644 "${WORKDIR}/can0.service" ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}/
    install -m 0644 "${WORKDIR}/can1.service" ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}/

}

FILES_${PN} = "\
    ${systemd_system_unitdir} \
    ${systemd_unitdir}/network/ \
"
```

```
$cat can0.service 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# For 2.0B legacy mode, arbitration bit rate (bitrate) and
# payload bit rate (dbitrate) have the same value - not higher than 1Mbps.
# CAN frames are limited to max 8 bytes in this case
# if target does not support FD, fg settings are not accepted by ip link set
[Unit]
Description=can0 interface setup

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/sbin/ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000
ExecStop=/sbin/ip link set can0 down

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

search can0.service on target roots but not found :

```
$cd lib/systemd/ && find -name "*can*"
--------------------------------------------
./system/wpa_supplicant.service
./system/wpa_supplicant-nl80211@.service
./system/wpa_supplicant@.service
./system/wpa_supplicant-wired@.service
```

Also I try to add systemd_%.bbappend with these file :
(Also systemd tree different with under code. can0.service is under the files folder near to service_%.bbappend file)

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI += "file://can0.service"

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "can0.service can1.service"

FILES_${PN} += "{sysconfdir}/systemd/system/* "

do_install_append() {
    install -d ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/*.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
}
```

can0.service created by above systemd_%.bbappend but not auto start at boot time. Just can0.service seems at /lib/systemd/system folder at target.

What is my mistake? Can somebody help me?

Comment: what does `journalctl -u can0` say?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk say nothing. (no entries)

Comment: is service even running? `systemctl status cat0`

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk Not running. My bbappend not add can0.service to rootfs.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk :  I finished the build. systemd_%.append add can0.service to /lib/systemd/system as I expected but :   $systemctl status can0 says that : 
��● can0.service - can0 interface setup   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/can0.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)   Active: inactive (dead)Jan 25 21:56:55 tqma8xqp-mba8xx systemd[1]: [[0;1;39m[[0;1;31m[[0;1;39m/lib/systemd/system/can0.service:16: Unknown lvalue 'FILES_${PN} +' in section 'Install'[[0m

Comment: start the service then

Answer (score 2):

The cat0 service status posted above shows that the service is not enabled.

You can enable this service using the command `systemctl enable cat0` and then try to reboot the system.

The services which are in enable state comes automatically after system reboot.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now if I write `systemctl enable can0` , every system reboot can0 up. But why I must write this command? Can't I do without this command to automatically after reboot? Also my first reboot when write image to sdcard linux wait

Answer (score 1):

`enable` will hook the specified unit into relevant places so that it will automatically start on boot or other situations depending on what's specified in the unit file.

As of systemctl version 220, enable and disable support a --now switch to start / stop services concurrent with the enabling / disabling.

e.g. `systemctl --now enable foobar.service`

Use systemctl --version to check your installed version.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your helps.Your suggestions very helpful for me. So I added what you say now everythings look fine but  not start (I think it must start). I get this log at @systemctl status can0 : `��● can0.service - can0 interface setup
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/can0.service; disabled; vendor preset: en
abled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
`

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
inherit systemd
```

and

```
SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE ??= "enable"
```

to the recipe did the trick for me. Now the service is auto-enabled after flashing the image.